Decisional Games same as Computational Games (if set is poly-sized)
Let us first define the two games. Let $\lambda$ be the security parameter and $S_{\lambda}$ be a set with at most $\textsf{poly}(\lambda)$ elements or for simplicity just a constant number of elements $c \in \mathbb{N}$.

A computational game $\textsf{Comp}$ is an interaction with an adversary $A$, such that at the end of the interaction the game outputs some $s \in S$. Now, the adversary sends some $s' \in S$ and the game outputs 1 if $s' = s$.

A decisional game $\textsf{Dec}$ is the same interaction with an adversary $A$, such that at the end of the interaction the game outputs some $s \in S$. But now, the game will flip a coin $c \leftarrow \{0,1\}$ and sends $a := s$ to the prover if $c = 0$, or a uniformly random $a \leftarrow S$ if $c = 1$. The adversary guesses the bit $c$ by sending $c' \in \{0,1\}$ to the game. The game outputs 1 if $c' = c$.


My professor told me that for poly-sized $S$ these two games are equivalent in the sense that if the advantage of one game is negligible, so is the other, i.e.
$|\text{Pr}[\textsf{Dec} \Rightarrow 1] - \tfrac{1}{2}| \leq \textsf{negl}(\lambda) \Leftrightarrow 
|\text{Pr}[\textsf{Comp} \Rightarrow 1] - \tfrac{1}{|S|}| \leq \textsf{negl}(\lambda).$
It is easy to show $\Rightarrow$ by constructing the obvious reduction. But I can't show the other direction.
Is this folklore in the crypto community? Do you have a book/paper/source/... where they show this fact by providing a reduction and the corresponding security analysis?
